# how to remove column from input file using perl

Tags: perl

How do I remove a column using perl? Can someone show me a basic example?  For example I want to remove `Date` and the date values:

Input file:

```
Date,Col2,Col3,Col4
9/14/2011,AA Host Info,Tier 1,Info
9/14/2011,AR Host Info T1,Tier 1,Info
```

Expected/New File:

```
Col2,Col3,Col4
AA Host Info,Tier 1,Info
AR Host Info T1,Tier 1,Info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/.*?,//;
```

Comment: It was convenient that it was the first column to be removed; that is particularly succinct.

Comment: @Jonathan: Also particularly helpful is that dates are unlikely to contain quoted commas. In the general case, using the `Text::CSV` module or the like is necessary, or at least very helpful.

Comment: wow. it seems so. is the `.*?` interepreted as give me everything from beginning of line to the comma? thanks again.

Comment: @cjd143SD: Everything up to the _first_ comma. (Without the `?`, it would be everything up to the _last_ comma.)